# How to use pundit scopes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authorization, pundit

I have just made the switch to Pundit from CanCan.  I am unsure about a couple of things, and how Pundit is best used.

For example:

If you have a resource that can have multiple parent objects, for instance lets say a Goal belongs to a student and instructor.  Therefor, a student can have many goals and an instructor can have many goals.  In a controller index action you might do:

```
if params[:student_id].present?
  @account = Student.find(params[:student_id])
  @goals = @account.goals
elsif params[:instructor_id].present?
  @account Instructor.find(params[:instructor_id])
  @goals = @account.goals
end
```

`params` are not usable inside policies, so the logic needs to be done here.  I think.  For what I can tell, if you skip the `policy_scope` you will get an unauthorized error when viewing the index page for goals.

Would you:

```
@goals = policy_scope(@account.goals)
```

OR

```
@goals = policy_scope(Goal.scoped).where( account_id: @account.id)
```

What happens when you throw a bunch of includes in the mix?

```
  @example = policy_scoped(@school.courses.includes(:account => :user, :teacher ))
```

Or when needed to order...is this correct?

```
 policy_scope(Issue.scoped).order("created_at desc")
```

When using scopes:  What is `:scope` here?  Is `:scope` an instance of the model being evaluated? I've tried accessing its attributes via `:scope`, but didn't work.

```
  class Scope < Struct.new(:user, :scope)
```

Answer (score 31):

Reading through this from a security perspective I can see a couple things that bear mentioning. For example, if you are allowing users to specify the `student_id` and `instructor_id` param fields, what's to stop them from passing in an ID for someone other than themselves? You don't ever want to let a user specify who they are, especially when you are basing policies on the users type.

For starters, I would implement Devise and add an additional boolean field called `instructor` that would be `true` when the user was an instructor but default to `false` for students.

Then your `User`s would automatically have an `instructor?` method defined, which will return `true` if the value in the `instructor` column is `true`.

You could then add a helper for students:

```
def student?
  !instructor?
end
```

Now using Devise (which gives us access to a `current_user` variable) we can do things like `current_user.instructor?` which will return `true` if they are an instructor.

Now on to the policy itself. I just started using Pundit a few weeks ago, but this is what I'd do in your situation:

```
class GoalPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < GoalPolicy
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user  = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      @scope.where(user: @user)
    end
  end
end
```

Then your (I'm assuming `GoalsController` class and `index` method) method can look like:

```
def index
  policy_scope(Goal) # To answer your question, Goal is the scope
end
```

If you wanted to order you could also do

```
def index
  policy_scope(Goal).order(:created_at)
end
```

I just realized that you asked this question half a year ago, but hey! Maybe it'll answer some questions other people have and maybe I'll get some feedback on my own budding Pundit skills.

Comment: it would probably be better to use getter methods to fetch `user` and `scope` inside `resolve`, also make them part of the private interface.

Answer (score 0):

Follow @Saul's recommendation on adding `devise` or other means of authentication.

Then you'll want to do this (`Entity` is `Goal` in your case):

```rb
@entities = policy_scope(Entity).where(...)
```

In `entity_policy.rb`:

```rb
class EntityPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
    def resolve
      # Here you have access to `scope == Entity` and `user == current_user`
      scope.where(entity: user.entity)
    end
  end
end
```

You might wonder why is `where` duplicated. The answer is (and here is the answer to your question): they serve different purposes. Although currently they are identical, but consider this:

You now have an `admin` user who has access to everything. Your policy changes:

```rb
class EntityPolicy < ApplicationPolicy
  class Scope < ApplicationPolicy::Scope
    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.where(entity: user.entity)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you have organizations with goals and the following restful endpoint:

`/organizations/:organization_id/goals`

When a user visits `/organizations/1/goals` you want to make sure the user is only allowed access to goals when the user is part of the organization:

`scope.where(organization: user.organization)` in the policy

And you also want to make sure that when an admin visits they can only see the goals related to that organization:

`policy_scope(Goal).where(organization_id: params[:organization_id])` in the controller.